# Hibernate Multitenancy and Spring Batch Integration

Tags: spring-batch, multi-tenant

We have a web application which is using spring transaction management with hibernate multi schema per tenant setup were tenant get resolved based on request url. I would like to do some tenant specific spring batch job based on a web request, within my understanding the datasource provided to the spring batch doesn't have the capability of identifying the tenant and insert job instance data to the respective tenant schema. I guess we can add tenant id to job parameter and make it unique job per tenant which resides on the default schema. But my requirement is to keep the job instance data in tenant specific schema and get job & run job based on tenant id. Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have good news and bad news. The good news is that this is easy to do. The default `JobRepository` (what reads/writes job metadata into the database) is stateless in the sense that if the `DataSource` you provide to it is tenant-aware, then it goes into the correct schema. So all you need is to do is provide Spring Batch with a data source that returns a contextually correct connection. For instance, you make sure that the data source, before returning the connection, sets the correct schema on it. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value='thread', proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource original = new JdbcDataSource(
        url:'jdbc:h2:mem:temp_db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1',
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'sa',)
    new DataSource() {
        @Delegate
        DataSource delegate = original

        @Override
        Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            String schema = schemaHolder().schema
            original.connection.with {
                it.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA $schema")
                // in other databases, the syntax may be different, e.g.
                //it.createStatement().execute("USE $schema")
                it
            }
        }

        @Override
        Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
            connection
        }
    }
}
```

In this example (in Groovy), when I return a connection from an H2 in memory database I set the correct schema. See the [full example](https://gist.github.com/6b0619a2e28ec3b36739). I use the Spring `thread` scope for telling each thread which schema it should use, but you can use whatever means you want to determine the correct schema in your data source.

Now, the bad news. If you actually run the full example, you'll likely get a failure like this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1 with wrong version (2), where current version is 1
```

The reason is that Spring Batch does have one nasty bit of global state -- the static variable `StepSynchronizationManager.manager` includes a map called `contexts` where it has stored all the step execution contexts currently active. This is a map whose key is `StepExecution`. `StepExecution::equals` is defined in such a way that two instances with the same job instance id, same step name and same id will compare equal. If you happen to have two jobs with same (autogenerated) id running at the same time, each running two steps with the same (autogenerated) id and the same name, you will have trouble. It's quite unlikely that this will happen in the real world, but it's something you should be aware of.

Comment: Thanks @Artefacto, let me try this... hope we can create unique job id per tenant with job parameter ?

Comment: @Nick The job id is selected used a sequence/autoincrement column, so changing the job parameters won't help. But the problem is more theoretical than anything. Naturally, the job/steps ids will diverge anyway, as you'll have more jobs for some schema than others (presumably).

Comment: i couldn't convert this to java implementation, can give some idea how to do this in java?.

Comment: @Nick What in particular? `@Delegate` just implements the remaining methods of `DataSource` in such a way that the call is forwarded to `delegate`.

Comment: there is no JdbcDataSource or Delegate classes i can see in my classpath, if you can point me to any sample github project with java could be helpful.

Comment: Please vote https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2480 to add inbuilt support in spring batch itself.